# How To Store JWT Token In Cookie in ASP.NET Core 3 SPA App

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I've got a default ASP.NET Core 3 app that I've built using the latest "create-react-app" template.  that is, in the startup.cs, I have the following code that instantiates the JWT Token generator that I assume uses OpenID. I've created the React template, but I don't think that matters in this case.,

```
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

After logging in, I can see a cookie that is stored that is not my JWT Token (which is what I want). The cookie doe shave the property `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` which I assume somehow is related to the JWT Token but I don't know how.

I want to store the JWT Token as a cookie parameter that so it gets posted back to the server with the next request.  How can I store that JWT signed token as a cookie inside my asp.net core 3 app?

Comment: Assuming the client side is a browser, can't you just put it into `sessionStorage`?

Comment: I need it in the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

For JWT Authenticaiton, it checks the request by the header `authorization: Bearer`. There is no need to store the token in the cookies.

If you watn to get the token for custom authentication, you could try to get it from header.

For passing through jwt authentication, you need to pass the token with the authorizaion header instead of cookies.

Update:

For React and Identity library, the authenticaiton is through `AuthorizeService.js` and you could access the token by `User` below:

```
async signIn(state) {
    await this.ensureUserManagerInitialized();
    try {
        const silentUser = await this.userManager.signinSilent(this.createArguments());
        this.updateState(silentUser);
        return this.success(state);
    } catch (silentError) {
        // User might not be authenticated, fallback to popup authentication
        console.log("Silent authentication error: ", silentError);

        try {
            if (this._popUpDisabled) {
                throw new Error('Popup disabled. Change \'AuthorizeService.js:AuthorizeService._popupDisabled\' to false to enable it.')
            }

            const popUpUser = await this.userManager.signinPopup(this.createArguments());
            this.updateState(popUpUser);
            return this.success(state);
        } catch (popUpError) {
            if (popUpError.message === "Popup window closed") {
                // The user explicitly cancelled the login action by closing an opened popup.
                return this.error("The user closed the window.");
            } else if (!this._popUpDisabled) {
                console.log("Popup authentication error: ", popUpError);
            }

            // PopUps might be blocked by the user, fallback to redirect
            try {
                await this.userManager.signinRedirect(this.createArguments(state));
                return this.redirect();
            } catch (redirectError) {
                console.log("Redirect authentication error: ", redirectError);
                return this.error(redirectError);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the Reason I need the cookie is that I’m posting back with JavaScript and the html request is not from the asp.net core server.  Previously, after login, it was and that is what set the auth cookie.  I need to now use the bearer token and can’t find it.  It’s not in the cookie.

Comment: @PeterKellner How did you request the token? In server side, you could try `var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");`

Comment: @PeterKellner check the update for client to get the access token.

Comment: I put this code in my controller and it returns token null when I'm logged in.  `public IEnumerable<SessionRec> GetSessionRecs()
        {
            var token = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result;`